# Matlab 3D plot plotting weird lines?

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d, plot, line

I have 3 arrays `X, Y, Z` that look something like this:

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
z = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9]
```

Then I am plotting these points with `plot3(x,y,z)`.
However the result is something unexpected.. It's basically meant to appear like a log-graph, it does this but it also has extra lines. I have no idea how it's happening, maybe someone here can enlighten me!

Here is an example of my graph (obviously I've plotted my values for `X, Y, Z` and the arrays above are just an example of what they look like):
[image]

As you can see, the bottom curved lines are the log-graph lines which I am happy to be seeing, but the one that appears above it confuse me. I tried displaying the `X Y Z` values that match the following pattern: `X is between 110 and 120` and `Y = 0.05`. This should theoretically give me **TWO** matches for each `X`. ie. Between `X = [110, 120]`, I should get 20 matches since the graph shows two lines hitting at the point `Y = 0.05` for each `X`.

To make it more clear what values of `X` are being graphed, it's basically increments of `0.1` so between `X = 120` and `X = 119`, it is plotting `119.0, 119.1, ... , 120.0`. In any case, only two points of `X, Z` hit `Y = 0.05` between `119-120`.

As I was saying, I checked for the values of `X, Z` that matched `Y = 0.05` and it only returns **ONE** result per `X`. That is, for `X = [110, 120]`, only 10 matches returned. These values were values on the bottom lines (ie. the log-graph lines) and **NOT** the top line. So effectively, these lines are not meant to exist. They are definitely hitting `Y = 0.05` and are between `X = [110, 120]` so they should be appearing as a match..

So there you have it. Not really sure what's going on!
If someone could help, that'd be great.

EDIT - More Info.
Even manually putting the `X, Y` values to the function which returns `Z` never reaches the values on the upper line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example for `x`, `y` and `z` actually illustrates your problem quite well.
You are not plotting individual curves (one for each log-plot) but rather one continuous curve. Hence your *extra lines* are in fact connecting one end of a log curve to the beginning of the next.
You have to break up your plot command.

**Edit**
In the end it will require knowledge of your dataset, but for the `x`, `y`, `z` you provided above, this will work to produce three independent curves instead of one:

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
y = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
z = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9];

DATASET_SIZE = 3;

hold on;

for i=1:size(x,2)/DATASET_SIZE

    plot3(x((i-1)*DATASET_SIZE+1:i*DATASET_SIZE),y((i-1)*DATASET_SIZE+1:i*DATASET_SIZE),z((i-1)*DATASET_SIZE+1:i*DATASET_SIZE));
    plot3(x(i*DATASET_SIZE+1:2*DATASET_SIZE),y(i*DATASET_SIZE+1:2*DATASET_SIZE),z(i*DATASET_SIZE+1:2*DATASET_SIZE));
    plot3(x(2*DATASET_SIZE+1:3*DATASET_SIZE),y(2*DATASET_SIZE+1:3*DATASET_SIZE),z(2*DATASET_SIZE+1:3*DATASET_SIZE));

    view(3)

end
```

**Edit 2**

An easy way of finding out if this *"problem"* occured, is using the `Data Cursor` in the MATLAB plot window. Place it anywhere on your graph and use the `up` or `down` arrow keys to move around. If you can move along the entire length of the plot, it is a continuous line. Furthermore, you should see the `Cursor` jump from the "end" of one curve to the "start" of the next.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense I guess. How would I go about breaking up the plot command? Sorry, I just got into Matlab today so I'm very unfamiliar with it! Thanks.

Comment: I was wondering where that `Data Cursor` type feature was! Yep, sure enough when pressing up/down after clicking a point, the point hits the edge then immediately switches to the other side. Unfortunately even using the 3 plots you provided gives the same result (a log-type line and a line joining the two ends). At the moment I'm just plotting the points using `plot3(x, y, z, '.')`. It doesn't produce a nice looking graph but it'll have to do I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using surface(x,y,z) and addressed the issue by changing the renderer. MATLAB has 3 different renderers for plotting data and by default the openGL renderer plots as you have shown. You can view hwich renderer your figure uses with GET(gcf). You can change renderer as I have done using: set(gcf,'Renderer','painters')
The 3rd renderer I believe is zbuffer and may work as well.